# Symbol identification (DNP & 0R)

Tags: identification

I am looking into a part from a datasheet for the [AS7262](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/894933/AMSCO/AS7262.html). And there is a part that I'm not sure what it's suppose to represent.

[image]

I have no idea what exactly DNP and 0R are meant to represent. They look like resistors but I'm confused as to why they are labelled as "DNP" & "0R". Doesn't quite make sense to have a 0R resistor.

Full schematic: [image]

Please let me know if more information is needed to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"DNP" means "Do Not Populate" - put a place on the board for this resistor, but don't install anything.

0R means "Zero Ohm resistor".

That network is used to select one of two options on the board - if you omit the DNP resistor and install the 0R resistor, you select one option.  For another application, you would omit the 0R resistor, and install a 0R resistor in the "DNP" position.

Answer (score 3):

DNP stands for "Do Not Populate", so there should just be empty pads for that part.  "0R" is a zero ohm jumper, a standard chip resistor with (essentially) zero resistance. They're commonly used to set configurations and options on chips.  For example, your chip's I2C_ENB pin is used to "Select UART (Low) or I²C (High) Operation".  With the jumper installed as shown in the schematic, it's set to UART operation.  Swapping them will select I2C.

Answer (score 1):

These are logical instructions for assembly, R = 0 ohm is an SMD resistor to provide Logic "0".

But it is **missing a Notes section** on implications, such as the 0R serves as a logical disable = "0" jumper for port type.  ENB = UART (Low) or I²C (High) Operation

0R & No Connection (NC) or Do Not Populate (DNP) are instructions for the automation technologist to program assembly as instructed and the Engineer to understand how it works.  Of course, you can reverse those if you know the implications.

One should always document a schematic for the next poor engineer/tech who has to support your design. (lol)