# SPDT switch reference schematic working

Tags: spdt

May I know what is the function of the below highlighted discrete components in the Switch circuit?
[image]

Regards,
Chitharanjan M

Comment: DNP means Do Not Populate, so these components are not fitted and hence don't do anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symbol identification (DNP & 0R)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/618327/symbol-identification-dnp-0r)

Comment: @Finbarr Yes in the Design its DNP, but what is the function of that discrete,  why these are been used as optional (DNP)

Answer (score 0):

The combination of C199, R243 & R233 seems to be for the purpose of inrush current limit. R243-R233 combination also reduces the VGS of the PMOS when it is ON. See this for more explanation: https://www.powerctc.com/en/node/4564

C6-R1 combination appears to be a feedback from switch output to the gate. So, serves the purpose of ensuring that the output does not rise faster than a desired slew rate and hence also helps in reducing the inrush current.